# Is it possible to map a button and/or a system event to launch an android application?

Tags: android

Good evening I am considering creating an application on the android platform and I want to know if it is possible to launch an application based on a particular system event, like pressing and holding a specific button for a period of time (i.e. 3 secs and launch application)?

Comment: It should be. I know of at least two applications doing something like that. One is called QuickDesk and the other is called 'Gesture Search Bar', thought you should note that the Gesture Bar's long press on the search button doesn't work on the Droid X (because Verizon changed some of the system's code and the developer hasn't been able to find a workaround)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can map search + a key to open a particular application.  See [keyboard shortcuts to switch between applications](http://android-tips.com/use-keyboard-shortcuts-to-switch-between-applications/).  That is an OS level thing though, I'm not sure what it would have to do with developing your own application.

Answer (score 0):

Inside an activity it's easy, use the [Event Handlers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html#EventHandlers) combined with the [KeyEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html) class and launch your preferred activity with an intent.

Comment: I'm sorry, but how is this helpful?  OP is asking to launch an application based on a system event.  This only works for an activity, which means the user would have to had launch an app, then hit more buttons to get past the started activity...